# BULK INSERT with Excel from a VARBINARY(MAX) field

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, excel

```
BULK INSERT Communication.Message

FROM OPENROWSET('Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0',

'Excel 8.0;Database=C:\temp\Messages201101.XLS', [messages$])
```

How do I take the above and instead read Message.XLS from a Varbinary(max) field named FileBytes in a table named Attachments.FileContents? I already know how to stage it in the table by various methods-- I just do not know method to use a BULK INSERT from a VarBinary(max) field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Jet driver can't open a `VARBINARY` that contains the bytes of your file.  Looking at [this MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190312.aspx), the documentation doesn't talk about opening/mounting anything except files.  You would have to take the bytes out of `FileBytes`, write them to a file and then use *that* file in your `OPENROWSET` statement.